# Get key-value pairs from POST body in Restlets

Tags: java, restlet

This may or may not be the dumbest question ever.

I'm using Restlet.  When the client (which I do not control) POSTs to the URL, I can call the function:

`representation.getText();`

Which produces the following example list of key-value pairs in string form:

```
CallStatus=in-progress&CallerCountry=US&CalledZip=24013&ApiVersion=2008-08-01&CallerCity=ARLINGTON&CalledCity=ROANOKE&CallSegmentGuid=&CalledCountry=US&DialStatus=answered&CallerState=VA&CalledState=VA&CallerZip=22039
```

How can I access this data as a Map of key-value pairs in Restlet?

**ANSWER:**

```
Form newForm = new Form(getRequest().getEntity());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out these examples quoted from [restlet.org](http://wiki.restlet.org/docs_2.0/13-restlet/27-restlet/330-restlet/58-restlet.html) (a Form is like a Map):

#### Getting values from a web form

The web form is in fact the entity of the POST request sent to the server, thus you have access to it via request.getEntity().
There is a shortcut which allows to have a list of all input fields :

```
Form form = request.getEntityAsForm();
for (Parameter parameter : form) {
  System.out.print("parameter " + parameter.getName());
  System.out.println("/" + parameter.getValue());
}
```

#### Getting values from a query

The query is a part of the identifier (the URI) of the request resource. Thus, you have access to it via request.getResourceRef().getQuery().
There is a shortcut which allows to have a list of all "key=value" pairs :

```
Form form = request.getResourceRef().getQueryAsForm();
for (Parameter parameter : form) {
  System.out.print("parameter " + parameter.getName());
  System.out.println("/" + parameter.getValue());
}
```

Comment: Awesome, "getEntityAsForm()" was what I was looking for. The documentation says its depreciated and will be removed in version 2.1, I think now the "accepted" way to do it is: new Form(getRequest().getEntity())

Comment: Ah good catch!  I'll have to look again at our code and make sure we're using the newer form.  Good luck!

Comment: getEntityAsForm is now deprecated